# GCC constexpr allows add but not bitwise-or with address

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, constexpr

Consider this code:

```
#include <cstdint>

static int x = 0;

const uintptr_t arithmetic()
{
    static constexpr uintptr_t result = ((uintptr_t)&x) + 1u;
    return result;
}

const uintptr_t bitwise()
{
    static constexpr uintptr_t result = ((uintptr_t)&x) | 1u;
    return result;
}
```

GCC (all versions 4-9) compiles `arithmetic()` just fine, but rejects `bitwise()`:

```
<source>: In function 'const uintptr_t bitwise()':
<source>:13:57: error: '(((uintptr_t)(& x)) | 1)' is not a constant expression
   13 |     static constexpr uintptr_t result = ((uintptr_t)&x) | 1u;
      |                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Why?  Note that bitwise-or works fine in other constexpr use cases, but not this one.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/x5jbuU

Comment: Probably due to the fact that this particular `uintptr_t`'s geneology originates with a pointer. You can add stuff to a pointer, but you can't bitwise-or anything to pointers; and for `constexpr`, the compiler actually tries to evaluate stuff.

Comment: `static constexpr uintptr_t result = (uintptr_t)&x;` also fails.

Comment: @Evg: That's true, it does.  I wonder now if GCC is trying to reject all uses of pointers in constexpr and the `+` somehow makes it forget.

Comment: I think [this](https://godbolt.org/z/f3s5C8) is also interesting. `+ 1u` compiles, `+ 0u` doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t use `reinterpret_cast` (or a C-style cast that performs one) in a constant expression at all.  GCC either has a bug enforcing that, or is trying to be helpful to support some practical use case where `+` but not `|` is relevant.

Comment: GCC doesn't enforce such a restriction at all (Clang does, but I'm not asking about Clang).  Here's a silly demo: https://godbolt.org/z/suehtD

Comment: @JohnZwinck: That just shows the no-diagnostic-required for a constexpr function that can never be called in a constant expression; an attempt at such a call is rejected.

Comment: Is there a reference?

Comment: @tigertang: Do you just mean the [definition of a constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)?